# Error with JetBrains products 2016

Tags: linux, phpstorm, java

I try to install last version of PhpStorm and CLion, but license window doesn't work. If I run `/bin/inspect.sh` I see some errors:

```
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=350m; support was removed in 8.0
[    147]  ERROR - nse.impl.GeneralLicenseManager - No valid license found 
java.lang.Throwable
    at com.intellij.openapi.diagnostic.Logger.error(Logger.java:127)
    at com.intellij.ide.a.l.K.a(K.java:143)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.idea.MainImpl$1.start(MainImpl.java:48)
    at com.intellij.idea.StartupUtil.prepareAndStart(StartupUtil.java:173)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.idea.MainImpl.start(MainImpl.java:43)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManager$2.run(PluginManager.java:92)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[    148]  ERROR - nse.impl.GeneralLicenseManager - PhpStorm 2016.1  Build #PS-145.258.2 
[    148]  ERROR - nse.impl.GeneralLicenseManager - JDK: 1.8.0_77 
[    149]  ERROR - nse.impl.GeneralLicenseManager - VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 
[    149]  ERROR - nse.impl.GeneralLicenseManager - Vendor: Oracle Corporation 
[    149]  ERROR - nse.impl.GeneralLicenseManager - OS: Linux
```

I tried with open-jdk8 and oracle jdk 8 the same problem. My OS is Debian 8.2

Comment: Check your idea.log for any hints: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/207241085-Locating-IDE-log-files (when you run actual product and not `inspect.sh`)

Comment: you must be update java package.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, you must be update java package.
Hope your issue is resolved by updating.